# What is the value of multiple Hybris extensions?

Tags: spring, architecture, sap-commerce-cloud

This is a question about web based software architecture.  I am a Hybris newbie, but as I understand it, you can create a full Spring MVC app in one Hybris extension.  What is the *value* of breaking out components of that app into multiple Hybris extensions?  Are there web app features or architectural value (e.g. maintainability, extensibility, performance, etc...) that you can only realize by using multiple extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So Hybris is based on the concept of being flexible and modular, allowing new functionality to be plugged in where needed via extensions. An extensions is an encapsulated piece of the Hybris Suite that can contain whatever you need it to contain, I.E. storefront, hMC, backoffice, etc. By default extensions are completely independent, however you can create dependencies between extensions no problem.

Say you're building an application that you want to have a section in the hMC, a frontend and some functionality in the backoffice too. In general you would have 4 extensions here:

- a core extension for the model, services, interceptors, etc
- hMC extension
- frontend extension, pluggable frontend
- backoffice extension

The real value of extensions is they allow hybris to be flexible and modular allowing for easy migration from one version of hybris to another.

Comment: that all makes sense.  except in your example, typically i have used spring and tiles and the file system to have those four components properly organized (URL mapping, model src versus controllers src etc...).  so the alternative would be to put those four functions in one extension.  i am sure that is wrong ))).  i just want to know why....  for example, does hybris require that all URI's in an extension start with a specific root?  so if i wanted http://dom.com/admin and http://dom.com/webapp i must use two extensions?

Comment: I do believe that hybris does require all URI's in an extension start with a specific root. I maybe wrong on that but from what I've seen from what I've worked on it seems to be the case. The main thing for extensions from what I've seen is the flexibility and modularity it provides.